# Javascript not loading in Rails Test Environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I can't get Javascript to load in the browser in the rails test environment. This is problematic for cucumber selenium tests through capybara. Here's my `test.rb` (the default as far as I know)

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
end
```

This results in a concatinated application.js with everything. I've tried adding `config.assets.debug = true` so that the assets aren't concatinated, and then only *sometimes* the javascript is loaded. If I copy over `development.rb` it seems to work, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was the `less-rails-bootstrap` version 3.0.1 gem was loading twitter/bootstrap in the wrong order due to inter-dependencies. We never noticed this is in development because Rails does not compress assets in the development environment, by default. So those particular files weren't being loaded, but they didn't keep all of our javascript from loading like they were in test.

Upgrading to `less-rails-bootstrap` 3.0.3, or requiring individual components of twitter/bootstrap in the correct order in application.js solved the problem.

Comment: how were you able to see the load order of the gem and actually debug this problem? Going through something similar now (bunch of inter-dependencies messing up stuff.) Would be useful to know your best practices and debugging theses

Comment: @Borat.sagdiyev I really do not recall, sorry. I haven't worked in Rails in a few years.